# Project Euler #8 Code -- Do While loop not executing all of code more than once -- [c++]

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve Project Euler Problem #8. I have written some code that I think should be able to solve it here. It's probably not the most efficient algorithm, but I think it should work. What happens on output is that it executes all of the for loops and the if statement the first time through, and then on subsequent passes through the do while loop, it only iterates the variable "position" but does executes none of the other code. Here is what I have. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, the task of problem #8 is to find which 13 consecutive digits of the given 1000 digit number have the greatest product. As of now, my code multiplies together the first 13 digits perfectly, and then fails to move on. It's very strange behavior to me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char num[1001] = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    int position = 0;
    unsigned int product_holder = 1;
    unsigned int product = 1;
    do{
        int holder[13] = {};
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
            holder[i] = num[i+position] - '0';
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
            product_holder *= holder[j];
        }
        if (product < product_holder){
            product = product_holder;
            std::cout << product << std::endl;
        }
        position++;
        std::cout << "The position is currently " << position << std::endl;
    }while(position != 9999);

    std::cout << product << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's _Project Euler_, and how is that relevant to your question please? Sure I'm playing possum here, to force you asking a question that's helpful for future research.

Comment: Project Euler is a pretty well known site that has various programming problems of increasing difficulty. Usually they are math based problems that would be incredibly time consuming to answer by hand. Most users see solving the problems as a way to learn to code better. I mentioned it in both my title and in my comment because when I looked for answers before posting, it seemed like people were familiar with the site and its problems. Also, I described specifically what I am trying to accomplish in the second paragraph of my comment. Find the greatest product of 13 adjacent digits.

Answer (score 2):

Your program leads to undefined behavior.

The line

```
holder[i] = num[i+position] - '0';
```

will cause the problem, because `num` is defined as `char num[1001];`, but `i + position` may go well over 10,000. So you're reading out of bounds of the `num` array, which is undefined behavior.

Here's an example output of the program:

```
...
The position is currently 7283 
The position is currently 7284
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

note: the output is non-deterministic because of the undefined behavior.

And here's the offending part, analyzed with gdb:

```
Core was generated by `./a.out'. 
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000400a07 in main () at eul.cpp:12 12
            holder[i] = num[i+position] - '0'; 
(gdb) print i 
$1 = 12 
(gdb) print position
$2 = 7284
(gdb) print num[i + position]
Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff27c11000
```